# Predication of click through ratio of news articles

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have a task to predict click through ratio of  news article based on historical data

I have tried to use key words of title of news articles as predication feature, use linear regression model to predicate click through ratio of news articles.But b/c of the curse of high dimensionality, the linear model fit the training date well, but predicate badly on testing data.

I seems the problem can't be solved by using linear modeling.Can someone shed light on me？

Comment: You may want to ask this on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Applying feature scaling may solve your problem.
For applying feature scaling you need to divide every value of each attribute by a certain value for that column (attribute). That value could be:

1. Maximum value
2. Mean value

etc.

Reduce every value of the attribute on a scale of -3 to +3, by applying feature scaling.

I would suggest you must divide every value by the mean value of that parameter.

For more better results, you may apply regularization of the parameters also.